# Can't find .apk of app i was developing

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Yesterday my HDD decided to die on me, which caused me to lose a lot of data, one of these bits of data being an application for Android I was developing. I read around and apparently you can decompile a .dex file or something. The only problem is there seems to be no mention of my application when exploring my phones hierarchy via my PC. It is definitely there somewhere as I can still run the application.

When my phone was being ran in debug mode and the application was run on eclipse it got installed. Can anyone advise me where I can find the install stuff etc for my app?

Thanks,
Rhys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the Android SDK installed, open up ddms and go to Device > File Explorer. Can you see it under <strike>System</strike> Data >  App?

(Note, if you're not rooted then you won't be able to open Data. Installed apps are protected on unrooted phones.)

Comment: Can only seem to get DDMS to work for my emulator atm. Had to reformat so not sure if everything is set up correctly

Comment: If it's showing your device as offline, don't forget to kill and restart the adb with the device connected. Also, sometimes it helps to restart your phone if you haven't done that in a while.

Comment: doing usb drivers etc now, should sort the ddms stuff out. will let you know then if i can find it (Thanks for taking some interest btw)

Comment: cant access my data folder, anyway to get a software-esq root. I could try one of them temp root apps on the store? would that have the desired effect?

Comment: I can't advise you on the best way to root it if you're worried about doing that, but you'll have to if you want to access your Data folder and get the .dex file of something you've installed on your phone.

Comment: I'll see how hard it will be to recreate what I did over the next few days, if not, I might risk my DHD :p (Perma root is always a bit risky on expensive phones :)) thanks for the help regardless

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in /data/app , I think you need root access to do that.

It will be in phone memory not sd card.